# Fastest way to map a new data frame column based on two other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
id|value
01| 100
01| 101
01| 300 #edited for case I originally left out
02| 300
03| 100
03| 101
04| 100
```

and I would like to add a new column that looks at both the id and the values assigned to each id.

For example:
 If an id has both a value 100 and 101 I will add it to category a.
 If an id has a value of 300 I will add it to category b.
 If an id has only one value (either 100 or 101, not both) assign it to category c.

result:

```
id|value|category
01| 100 |  a
01| 101 |  a
01| 300 |  b #edited for case I originally left out
02| 300 |  b
03| 100 |  a
03| 101 |  a
04| 100 |  c
```

I understand I can loop through it and assign the category, but my question is whether there is a faster vectorized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options with `data.table`

We could get the number of elements per 'id' that are '100', '101' and add them together.  The output would be 0, 1, or 2 corresponding to none, single element, or both present.  This can be converted to `factor` and change the `labels` so that 'a' would be '2', 'b' as '0' and 'c' as '1'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, indx:=sum(unique(value)==100)+sum(unique(value)==101), 
  id][, category:=factor(indx, levels=c(2,0,1), labels=letters[1:3]) ][,
   indx:=NULL][]
#    id value category
#1:  1   100        a
#2:  1   101        a
#3:  2   300        b
#4:  3   100        a
#5:  3   101        a
#6:  4   100        c
```

Or we could create a named vector ('v1') and use that as index to map the character elements (`toString(...)`) grouped by 'id'.

```
v1 <- c('100, 101' = 'a', '300'='b', '100'= 'c', '101'='c')
setDT(df2)[, category := v1[toString(sort(unique(value)))], by=id][]
#    id value category
#1:  1   100        a
#2:  1   101        a
#3:  2   300        b
#4:  3   100        a
#5:  3   101        a
#6:  4   100        c
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset and the new condition, we can modify the first solution as

```
 setDT(df3)[, indx:= sum(unique(value)==100) + sum(unique(value)==101), id][, 
 category:= factor(indx, levels=c(2,0,1), labels=letters[1:3])][
 value==300, category:='b'][, indx:=NULL][]
 #    id value category
 #1:  1   100        a
 #2:  1   101        a
 #3:  1   300        b
 #4:  2   300        b
 #5:  3   100        a
 #6:  3   101        a
 #7:  4   100        c
```

Or using the second option

```
  v1 <- c('100, 101' = 'a', '100, 101, 300' = 'a', '300'='b',
            '100'= 'c', '101'='c')
  setDT(df3)[, category := v1[toString(sort(unique(value)))], 
                by=id][value==300, category := 'b'][]
  #   id value category
  #1:  1   100        a
  #2:  1   101        a
  #3:  1   300        b
  #4:  2   300        b
  #5:  3   100        a
  #6:  3   101        a
  #7:  4   100        c
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), value = c(100L, 
101L, 300L, 100L, 101L, 100L)), .Names = c("id", "value"), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df3 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
value = c(100L, 101L, 300L, 300L, 100L, 101L, 100L)),
.Names = c("id", "value"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks, these work great. I am finding with my data, however, that I have some id's that belong in multiple categories. For example, id 1 can have values of 100, 101, and 300. I would then like the entries for values 100 and 101 to be category a, and the entry that has a value of 300 to map to category b.

Comment: I updated the tables in the original question. Thanks

Comment: @badger0053 I updated the solution.  Please check if that works.